# add multiple dropdown with same list values and add them in one List

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, flutter-getx

I'm creating a dynamic amount of dropdown and textformfields in flutter form. which means the user can add as many dropdown as they want. so I already achieve [image: this] and can control the values. but the value of the dropdown is returning null.

First I created a class to group them together

```
class _GroupControllers {
  TextEditingController phone = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  String? selectedCatagory;
  void dispose() {
    phone.dispose();
    email.dispose();
    selectedCatagory;
  }
}
```

then initialize them

```
  List<TextFormField> _phoneFields = [];
  List<TextFormField> _emailFields = [];
  List<_GroupControllers> _groupControllers = [];
  List<DropdownButtonFormField2> _categoryDropDown = [];
```

and I created a widget for adding them

```
Widget _addTile(int index) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text("Add Phone"),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final group = _GroupControllers();

                final phoneField = _generateTextField(group.phone,
                    "phone number", RegExp(r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10,12}$)'));

                final emailField = _generateTextField(
                    group.email,
                    "email",
                    RegExp(
                        r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+"));
                final categoryDropdown =
                    _generatedDropDown(category, group.selectedCatagory);

                index == 0
                    ? setState(() {
                        _groupControllers.add(group);
                        _phoneFields.add(phoneField);
                        _emailFields.add(emailField);
                        _categoryDropDown.add(categoryDropdown);
                      })
                    : setState(() {
                        _groupControllers.removeAt(index);
                        _phoneFields.removeAt(index);
                        _emailFields.removeAt(index);
                        _categoryDropDown.removeAt(index);
                      });
              },
              icon: index == 0
                  ? const Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    )
                  : const Icon(
                      CupertinoIcons.minus,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

then created their fields

```
DropdownButtonFormField2 _generatedDropDown(
      List<String> category, String? selected) {
    final group = _GroupControllers();
    return DropdownButtonFormField2(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
      ),
      isExpanded: true,
      hint: const Text(
        'Select Category',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
      ),
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
        color: Colors.black45,
      ),
      iconSize: 30,
      buttonHeight: 60,
      buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
      items: category
          .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: item,
                child: Text(
                  item,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null) {
          return 'Please select Catagory.';
        }
      },
      onChanged: (value) {
        //Do something when changing the item if you want.
        setState(() {
          selected = value.toString();
          group.selectedCatagory = value.toString();
        });
      },
      onSaved: (value) {
        selected = value.toString();
        group.selectedCatagory = value.toString();
      },
    );
  }

  TextFormField _generateTextField(
      TextEditingController controller, String hint, RegExp pattern) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter ${hint}';
        } else if (!pattern.hasMatch(value)) {
          return 'Enter a valid ${hint}';
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: hint),
    );
  }
```

the in my `ListView.builder()`

```
                Column(
                  children: [
                    _addTile(index),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Phone Number:",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: width * 0.04,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              letterSpacing: width * 0.002),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        _phoneFields[index],
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: height * 0.005,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Email:",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: width * 0.04,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              letterSpacing: width * 0.002),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        _emailFields[index],
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: height * 0.005,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Category:",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: width * 0.04,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              letterSpacing: width * 0.002),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        _categoryDropDown[index]
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: height * 0.005,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

so why is it not working?